# Render app views per user agent in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, user-agent, ejs

I'm working on a Node.js/Express that uses EJS and trying to render certain views on desktop or mobile.

I've added the following middleware to return the user agent in my `app.js`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.ua = req.get('User-Agent');
  next();
});
```

Next, if I echo `<%= ua %>` in my view, I successfully get the user agent, but I'm not sure how to actually check specific agents.

I tried `<$ if(ua.match(/iPhone)) { %>` as a quick example, but got a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors:

1) You started with a `$` inside your embedded script. You should instead use a `%`.

2) You need to close out your regex with a `/`.

Something like this:

```
<% if(ua.match(/Intel/)) { %>
  <%= ua %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Oh, man, that's embarrassing. Damn EJS. I rarely make syntax errors, but thanks for the regex tip!

Comment: No worries... you showed me a new way to get the `User-Agent` header in Express. Fair trade!